# Loop through a list of array in angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How do I loop through an array and retrieve the inner value of that response and push it to a angular array object.

What I have written so far:

```
 angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
    $scope.FbPages = $scope.FbPages.concat($scope.item.name);})
```

The response from Facebook looks like this

```
accounts: Object
data: Array[11]
0: Object
access_token: "CAAWlw4AuZARMBALL2YV034jGClKDR32L2ZBHxP1C"
category: "Political Organization"
id: "104147073282632"
name: "Stalwarts of INC"
perms: Array[6]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
access_token: "CAAWlw4AuZARMBAN7ZB9vDiCeR1vNbDyIAyK"
category: "Computers/Technology"
id: "1495612094063208"
name: "Latch UI"
perms: Array[6]
__proto__: Object
```

I need to retrieve the name of each page and append that vale into FbPages.

Comment: set the data array to scope and do ng-repeat. please share your html in the question

Comment: If you log "item" in the function to the console, what is the output?

Comment: @LibinJoseph, will proceed once you check and start reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
    $scope.FbPages = $scope.FbPages.concat( /*$scope*/ item.name);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array and them push each item (or the relevant portion):

```
$scope.FbPages = [];
angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
    $scope.FbPages.push(item.name);
});
```

Comment: item.name returns undefined

Comment: Maybe because you are iterating through the response object values? What happens if you log item?

Comment: @BMcV : No, I console.log item.data. It gace me undefined

Comment: Do a `console.log(item)` to see what is being iterated.

Answer (score -1):

Try like below.

Setting Scope Variable Array.

```
  if(angular.isArray(response.data) ) {
    $scope.FbPages = [];
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(item) {
        $scope.FbPages.push(item.name);
    });
  }
```

ng-repeat Example:

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in FbPages">
  <li>{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: item.name returns undefined

Comment: Added one more condition called isArray. before this console your response variable and let us know